# How to enforce Prism Region A loads prior to Region B?

Tags: prism

There are two different view models (Sender, Receiver) are located in two different Prism regions and those intend to communicate. But on application start up the view model that would receive the events is not yet created. How can I enforce to load and activate first the region holds the receiver view model ? I attempted to

1. `containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ReceiverView>(RegionNames.X);`
2. `regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.X, RegionNames.X);`

Or shall I take the region and `region.Activate(object view);` ?

Comment: I vote for "wrong question" - better ask for a different communication system than simple event aggregator.

Comment: @Haukinger Or is there a way to buffer the events on the aggregator if we cannot impact the region life cycle ?

Comment: Prism's event aggregator doesn't do this. You're not _forced_ to use it, though.